# How to get the Avg. RAM and CPU usage for 3 java services which I'm running on Linux machine for load testing metrics

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, testing, load

I'm using an AWS remote Linux machine for for Load testing.

Presently I'm using "top" command

[image]

Then I also piped few more commands in it to get java specific services

[image]

For RAM usage I'm using "free" command.
[image]

Now I wanted to calculate average CPU and RAM % while I run the application, lets say for 10-15 testing flow, how may I calculate that?

Comment: Please post textual data as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution so posting it, we can use PerfMon Plugin with Jmeter and Install server agent on the desired remote Linux machine to accomplish our task.

https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/04/07/how-to-monitor-the-servers-system-resource-using-jmeter-plugin/

other Solution remains only with the shell script only.

```
for i in {1..200}; do
    sleep 0.25
    top -p 5431 -p 5476 -p 5442 -b -n1 |
    awk '{print$1,$9,$10,$NF}' |
    tail -3
done >> 25MedOnce.csv
```

There is another way as well

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    sleep 2
    systemd-cgtop -m |
    grep -e service1 -e service2 -e service3 |
    tail -3
done
```

Here we need to mention the service names and it will show the CPU and MEM %

Comment: For the first code snipped, how should the PIDs 5431, 5476, and 5441 be chosen?

Comment: ohh sorry I forgot to add, 

I used --> ps -ef | grep 'java'
as the services I was monitoring for were java spring boot services. 
Once we get the results in a csv file we can easily use excel formulas to get the average RAM and CPU usages.